# Equations of motions of $\mathcal{L}[\phi,x]=\phi[x]$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus

Equations of motions of

$$
\mathcal{L}[\phi,x]=\phi[x]
$$

where $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

The Euler-Lagrange equations are:

$$\partial_\mu\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi}$$

Applying this to the $L[\phi,x]$, I get:

$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial _{\mu}\phi)}=0\\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi}=1\\
0=1
$$

Its a bit unexpected. Does it mean that are no solutions?

Comment: The classical Lagrangian $L=x$ has the same property, no need to involve QFT. First of all there is no kinetic term so "nothing propagates". Second, this potential has no minimum. As this Lagrangian has no physical reality, similar problem occurs (if you look close enough) in the $\phi^3$ theory

Comment: @Alexander $L[x]=x$ does not depend upon any function and thus one cannot take the Euler-Lagrange equations. Perhaps you mean $L[f,x]=f[x]$? In this case, taking the equation fo motion with respect to $f$ will also yield $1=0$ as the equations of motion.

Comment: I wrote about classical Lagrangian. No need for field theory or field functions to "expose" the inadequacy of these types of Lagrangians.

Comment: @Alexander In the case of $L[x]=x$, would you not get: 
$$
\frac{\partial L[x]}{\partial f} = \partial_x \frac{\partial L[x]}{\partial (\partial_x f)}\\
0=0
$$
as opposed to $1=0$?

Comment: @Alexander Oh okay, I just realized a misunderstanding of mine. In $L[x]=x$, then $x$ is the function because the variable is still $t$. So the Euler-Lagrange equations are

$$
\frac{\partial L[x]}{\partial x} = 0 \implies \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} =0 \implies 1=0
$$

So, what mathematical assumption is violated when one creates a Lagrangian of type $L[x]=x$? (one is not supposed to get $1=0$)

Comment: @Alexander Actually, my previous comment is wrong. If $x$ is the function, then it means the Lagrangian is dependant upon $t$ and that $x$ is a function $t$. So we get back to my initial formulation $L[x,t]=x[t]$.

Comment: This "0=1 phenomenon" also occurs when you try to compute the extrema of e.g. $f(x) = x$ (as an ordinary function) by solving the condition $f'(x) = 0$. What does this have to do with physics?

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3732738/11127

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a subtle point to the action principle. If we have some action $S$, then a field configuration $\phi$ extremises it if it can satisfy the conditions,

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \phi} - \partial_\mu\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} = 0$$

however it is not asserting that this is true. Only that if $\phi$ extremises the action, it is, which is why it might be better sometimes to write a $?$ above the $=$ sign, if you like.

In this case we have $1=0$ as the condition. Thus, no field $\phi$ can satisfy this condition. There is no issue. To be explicit:

$$\mathrm{IF} \quad \phi_i \, | \, \delta S = 0 \implies \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \phi^i} = \partial_\mu\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi^i)} \right)$$

In your case the first "if statement" is not satisfied, so there is no Euler-Lagrange equation claimed. When we do use Euler-Lagrange equations, we are assuming they hold true and assuming that there are $\phi^i$ extremising the action. Then we normally get a sensible equation, and solve it to find them. But implicit is our assumption that there exists such solutions in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Let's instead with a Lagrangian
$$\cal L_{\mathrm{mine}}[\phi;\alpha] = \frac{\alpha}{2}(\partial \phi)^2 + \phi,$$
where $\alpha$ is a parameter you can tune (which we take for conreteness to be $\alpha\geqslant 0$). Then of course,
$$\cal L_\mathrm{yours}[\phi]=\cal L_\mathrm{mine}[\phi;0].$$
However, by a simple field redefinition $\phi\mapsto \sqrt{\alpha}\phi$ my Lagrangian becomes
$$\cal L_\mathrm{mine}[\phi;\alpha] = \frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2 + \frac{1}{\alpha}\phi,\tag{1}$$
which is now in canonical form. Of course, the meaning of field redefinition is that the content of the two Lagrangians is the same. However now the equations of motion of (1) give
$$\partial^2\phi=\frac{1}{\alpha}.$$
Taking $\alpha\to 0$ gives that the second derivative of $\phi$ is infinite, this is just because the potential $V[\phi]=-\phi$ is unbounded; you have to go all the way to $+\infty$ to find its minimum.